# php randomly execute between two values in a 24hr period

Tags: php

I have created an array with the times (according to the random number generated between the values supplied) 
I now need it to execute at those specific times ( a simple echo 'hello'; would work )
script will run for 24hrs and i need it to execute a command at those times supplied in the array

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$start_num = '500';
$end_num   = '900';
$rand_num  = rand($start_num, $end_num);

$array = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= $rand_num; $x++)
{
$fml = rand(0, 86400);
//echo $fml."\n";
$array[] = $fml;
}
sort($array);
//print_r($array);
//echo $rand_num;
?>
```

any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You may need to use CRON.

Answer (score 2):

`CRON` is for fixed-time intervals. You can't do random with it. But what you could do is have two scripts. One simple one that runs at midnight and schedules the real job using `at` - `at` is for one-shot jobs at specified times.  So you repeatedly run the random scheduler, which schedules the "real" job at random times.

The other option is to simply use `at` to schedule the real job, and then the job reschedules itself again using `at` using a random future time. The danger with this if that your script bails for whatever reason before it can re-schedule itself, that's it - no more jobs will be run. The cron+at combination is a bit more complicated, but more reliable.